# $_Request not sending all data

Tags: php, html

I have been given below code by a client who completed the previous modules using a bad programmer. The code sends subject, start date, end date, centre id and year to the the new url loaded in the below code,

```
      $( ".centre-selection" ).each(function() {
    $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-subject')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&StartDate='+ $( this ).attr('report_date_start')+ '&EndDate='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end'));
  } );
```

The above code sends the centre id and year but does not send the other data.

```
<?php 
    $base_name = "Progress";
    $module_action = $_REQUEST['module_action'];
    ?>

<script src="../assets/plugins/table2excel/jquery.table2excel.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {$('li#module_report_pc_attendance_register').addClass( "active" );
        $('.content-header h1').html('Progress Report<small> report</small>');

    });
</script>
<style>
#centre{
    display:none;
}
#selected-centre button {
    margin-right: -10px;
}
div#pc-scrool {
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.subject-table-code {
    display: -webkit-box;
    width: 2pt;
    height: 2pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 1pt;
}
.report td {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    padding: 1mm !important;
    margin: 10px !important;
    position: relative;

}
.tr-edited{
    background-image: url(../assets/img/pat.svg);
    background-size: 70px;
}
.off {
    background: #ABAAAA;
}
.registered_yes_am {
    background: #ffffff !important;
}
.registered_yes_pm {
    background: #ffffff !important;
}

td.day-full {
    border-top-color: black !important;
    border-top-style: solid !important;
    border-top-width: 3px !important;
    border-left-color: black !important;
    border-left-width: 3px !important;
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-color: black !important;
    border-right-width: 3px !important;
}
td.day-am {
    border-top-color: black !important;
    border-top-style: solid !important;
    border-top-width: 1px !important;
    border-left-color: black !important;
    border-left-width: 3px !important;
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-color: black !important;
    border-right-width: 1px !important;
}
td.day-pm {
    border-top-color: black !important;
    border-top-style: solid !important;
    border-top-width: 1px !important;
    border-left-color: black !important;
    border-left-width: 1px !important;
    border-bottom-color: black !important;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-right-color: black !important;
    border-right-width: 3px !important;
}
td.day-full {
    width: 16.666666%;
}

.day-pm, .day-am {
     width: 1%;
    <?php if($_REQUEST[page_type] == 'minimal'){ ?>
    width: 2mm;
    height: 2mm;
    <?php } ?>
}
.attendence-cell{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bolder;

}
.attendence-cell a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
td.total-name-cell {
    font-size: 10pt;

}
td.pupil-name-cell {
    font-size: 10pt;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.not-started{
background-image: url(../assets/img/pat.svg);
background-size: 70px;
background-color: #ABAAAA;
}
</style>

<?php
    switch ($module_action){
        /////////////////////////////
        default:
            ?>

<?php if($_REQUEST[page_type] != 'minimal'){ ?>

    <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="row" id="selected-centre" style="display: none;">

        <a href="?module=module_progress_report"><button id="selected-centre-back" class="btn bg-red margin"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></button></a> 
        <button id="selected-date" class="btn btn-flat margin" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: #00c0ef;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  <span></span></button> 
        </div>
    <div class="row" id='attendance-select-date'>
    <div class="col-md-3">

    <span >
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 range">
        <label for="class_date">Month report</label>
        <div class="input-group date">

            <input type="text" id="class_date" class="form-control"   name="report_date_start" ><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <!--
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="class_date">Week report</label>
        <div class="input-group date">

            <input type="text" id="class_date_week" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    -->
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 range">
        <label for="class_date">Custom range report</label>
        <div class="input-group date">

            <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="class_date_range">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="report_date_start" name="report_date_start" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" id="report_date_end" name="report_date_end" />
            </div>

        </div>

        </div>

    </div> </span>
    </div>



    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="row" id="centre-class-menu">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">      
                            <!--<img src="template_system/templates/<?= $Templates_Location; ?>/prv_mini.jpg" />-->

                          <!-- small box -->
                          <div class="small-box bg-aqua" style="background-color: #<?=stringToColorCode($Centre_Name)?> !important;">
                            <div class="inner">
                              <h4>Select Subject</h4>

                            </div>
                            <div class="icon">
                              <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                            </div>
                              <a href="#" class="small-box-footer centre-year-selection-1"  data-report-range="month">
                                  <strong>All Subjects<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></strong>
                            </a> 
                              <?php
                              $query = "SELECT * FROM subject";
                            //$query="SELECT * FROM $base_name";
                            $result = mysql_query($query);
                            while ($row39 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                $Referrer_ID = $row39['Subject_ID'];
                                $Referrer_Name = $row39['Subject_Name'];      
                                ?>
                             <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-subject="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>" data-report-range="month">
                                      <?=$Referrer_Name?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                            <?php } ?>

                          </div>
                    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable" id="alert">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4><i class="icon fa fa-info"></i> Select date range first!</h4>
                    You can choose 2 options<br>
                    <strong>'Month report'</strong> - report for all working days in selected month.<br>
                    <strong>'Custom range</strong> report' - report for all working days in selected days range. 
            </div>

                <div class="row" id="selected-centre" style="display: none;">

            <a href="?module=module_attendance"><button id="selected-centre-back" class="btn bg-red margin"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></i></button></a> <button id="selected-date" class="btn btn-flat margin" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: #00c0ef;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>  <span></span></button> <button id="selected-centre-name" class="btn btn-flat margin" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(119, 162, 237);"><i class="fa fa-building"></i>  <span>Hockley Centre</span></button> <button class="btn btn-flat margin" id="selected-centre-year" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(119, 162, 237);"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <span>Mixed</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="row clearfix" id="centre" >
            <div class="col-xs-12" >
            <?php
        $query1  = "SELECT * FROM Centre WHERE `Centre_Active` = 'yes'";
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
        while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
           $Centre_ID = $row1['Centre_ID'];
            $Centre_Name = $row1['Centre_Name'];
            $Centre_ContactName = $row1['Centre_ContactName'];
            $Centre_Address = $row1['Centre_Address'];
            $Centre_Postcode = $row1['Centre_Postcode'];
            $Centre_Tel = $row1['Centre_Tel'];
            $Centre_Fax = $row1['Centre_Fax'];
            $Centre_Email = $row1['Centre_Email'];
            $Centre_Active = $row1['Centre_Active'];
?>

                <!--<img src="template_system/templates/<?= $Templates_Location; ?>/prv_mini.jpg" />-->





              <!-- small box -->
              <div class="small-box bg-aqua" style="background-color: #<?=stringToColorCode($Centre_Name)?> !important;">
                <div class="inner">
                  <h4><?=$Centre_Name?></h4>

                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                  <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
                </div>
                  <?php
        $query_year  = "SELECT * FROM Year WHERE Year_Centre ='$Centre_ID' AND `Year_Active` = 'yes' ORDER BY Year_Name";
        $result_year = mysql_query($query_year);
        while ($row_year = mysql_fetch_array($result_year)) {
          $Year_ID = $row_year['Year_ID'];
$Year_Name = $row_year['Year_Name'];
$Year_Centre = $row_year['Year_Centre'];
$Year_Active = $row_year['Year_Active'];
?>
         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer centre-year-selection-1 centre-selection" data-centre="<?=$Centre_ID?>" data-year="<?=$Year_Name?>" data-year-name="<?=$Year_Name2[$Year_Name]?>" data-centre-name="<?=$Centre_Name?>" data-centre-color="#<?=stringToColorCode($Centre_Name)?>" data-attendance-check="">
                  <?=$Year_Name2[$Year_Name]?> <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
         </a>         
        <?php } //year loop ends ?>

              </div> <?php } // cemtre loop end ?>
            </div>

                <?php
        } //
?>


        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12">


    <?php
    //get values from menu screen

    $Centre_Selected_ID = $_REQUEST[Centre_Selected_ID];
    $Class_Selected_Year = $_REQUEST[Class_Selected_Year];




    if($Centre_Selected_ID && $Class_Selected_Year)
    {
    ?>
        <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#centre-class-menu').hide();
            $('#attendance-select-date').hide();
            $('#selected-centre').show();

        });
        </script>







    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#centre-class-menu').hide();
            $('#attendance-select-date').hide();
            $('#selected-centre').show();
            $('body').addClass("sidebar-collapse");



        });
        </script>                   

      <?php     


                        //PC report start
                        //



$report_range = $_REQUEST[report_range];
$report_date_start = $_REQUEST[report_date_start];
$report_date_end = $_REQUEST[report_date_end];
$report_referrer = $_REQUEST[Referrer];

//////////////////////////////////////
//function get_all_pupils_and_timetables($report_range, $report_date_start, $report_date_end, $report_referrer, $report_pupil);
//
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
include "pupils_timetable_maga_calss.php"; //////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//
//

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($Data_Range_Info); echo '</pre>';                  
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($PupilsArray_names[55]); echo '</pre>';


//REGISTER

?>





                        <table align="center">
                                                           <?php
        $query1  = "
                    SELECT progress_track.Progress_Report, Orders.OrderID
                    FROM time_table
                    INNER JOIN Orders
                    ON progress_track.Progress_Report=pupils.Pupils_ID
                    WHERE progress_track.CentreID =;
        ";
        $result = mysql_query($query1);
        while ($row_year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $Year_ID[] = $row_year['Progress_Report_ID'];
            echo $Year_ID;
        }
?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <span style="display:block;text-align: center;width: 100%;"><strong><big>Progress Report (<?php echo $_GET['report_date_start'];
                                    if($_GET['report_date_end']!= "undefined")  {
                                        echo " - ".$_GET['report_date_end'];
                                    }

                                    ?>)


                                    <?php
                                            $query2  = "
                                                        SELECT tutors.Tutors_Name,tutors.Tutors_Surname FROM tutors INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Tutor_ID=tutors.tutors_ID   
                                            ";
                                            $result = mysql_query($query2);
                                            while ($row_year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                $tutor= $row_year['Tutors_Name'];
                                                $tutor_last= $row_year['Tutors_Surname'];
                                            }
                                    ?>

                                    <br><span><?php echo $_GET['Subject'] ?> - Tutor: <?php echo $tutor." ".$tutor_last?></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Centre : Hockey Center</th>
                            <?php
                                            $query3  = "
                                                        SELECT pupils.pupils_Surname,pupils.Pupils_FirstName FROM pupils INNER JOIN progress_track ON progress_track.Progress_Report_Pupils_ID=pupils.pupils_ID 
                                            ";
                                            $result = mysql_query($query2);
                                            while ($row_year = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                                $pupil1= $row_year['Pupils_Surname'];
                                                $pupil2= $row_year['Pupils_FirstName'];
                                            }
                                    ?>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Centre : Magnet Center</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Centre : Hollymoor Center</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Centre : Erdington Center</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>




     <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $('#centre-class-menu').hide();
            $('#attendance-select-date').hide();
            $('#selected-centre').show();
            $('#selected-centre-name span').html('<?=$Centre_Name2[$Time_Table_Centre]?>');
            $('#selected-centre-year span').html('<?=$Year_Name2[$Time_Table_Year]?>');
            $('#selected-date span').html('');
            $('#selected-centre-year,#selected-centre-name').css('background-color','#<?php echo stringToColorCode($Centre_Name2[$Time_Table_Centre])?>');
        });
        </script>
  <?php if($_REQUEST[page_type] != 'minimal'){ ?>       
</div>
</div>
        </div>
  <?php } ?> 

    <?php

        } // * end if center and date is selected
    ?>


<?php if($_REQUEST[page_type] != 'minimal'){ ?>
<script>



$(function () {

     $("#save_excel").click(function(){
                $(".report").table2excel({
                  // exclude CSS class
                  exclude: ".noExl",
                  name: "Progress Report",
                  filename: "<?=$Referrer_Name2[$_REQUEST[Referrer]]?>Test <?=$Raport_Data_Renge_Start?> - <?=$Raport_Data_Renge_End?>"
                }); 
              });

    //$("#class_date").inputmask("yyyy/mm", {"placeholder": "yyyy/mm/"});

    $('#class_date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    endDate: "-infinity",
    minViewMode: 1,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    autoclose: true
});
    $('#class_date_week').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: "-infinity",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    autoclose: true
});
$('#class_date_range').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    weekStart: 1,
    endDate: "-infinity",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    clearBtn: true,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6",
    autoclose: true
});

});

$( document ).ready(function() {  

    if( !$('#class_date').val() ) {
          $('#centre-class-menu').slideUp();
             $( ".small-box-footer" ).click(function() {

                              //   $('.small-box-footer').slideToggle("fast");
                                // $('.inner').slideToggle("fast");
        $("#centre-class-menu").toggle();
$("#alert").toggle();
$("#centre").toggle();
$(".range").toggle();



          });
    }
    else{
        $('#centre-class-menu').slideDown();
        $('.centre-year-selection').attr('data-attendance-check', $('#class_date').val());
        $( ".small-box-footer" ).click(function() {
                          //   $('.small-box-footer').slideToggle("fast");
                            //   $('.inner').slideToggle("fast");
        $("#centre-class-menu").toggle();
        $("#alert").toggle();
        $("#centre").toggle();
        $(".range").toggle();


          });
    }    


              $( ".centre-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-subject')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&StartDate='+ $( this ).attr('report_date_start')+ '&EndDate='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end'));
          } );






});

//on change val in monthly date picker - The firing of the the subject
$("#class_date").change(function() {    

    if( !$('#class_date').val() ) {
          $('#centre-class-menu').slideUp();
          $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&?Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ '1'+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre'));
          });
    }
    else{
        $('#centre-class-menu').slideDown();
        $('.centre-year-selection').attr('data-attendance-check', $('#class_date').val());
        $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&report_date_start='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check')+ '&report_date_end='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&report_range=month');
          });
    }

});

//firing of subject ends
//on change val in custom range data picker
$("#report_date_end").change(function() {   

    if( !$('#report_date_end').val() ) {
          $('#centre-class-menu').slideUp();
          $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre'));
          });
    }
    else{
        $('#centre-class-menu').slideDown();
        $('.centre-year-selection').attr('data-attendance-check', $('#report_date_start').val());
        $('.centre-year-selection').attr('data-attendance-check-end', $('#report_date_end').val());
        $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&report_date_start='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check')+ '&report_date_end='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&report_range=range');
          });
    }

});




/////////
function check_class_date(){

    if( !$('#class_date').val() ) {
          $('#centre-class-menu').slideUp();
        $(".centre-year-selection").each(function() {
            $(".centre-year-selection").toggle();
        });

         $(".centre-year-selection").click(function(){
        $("#centre-class-menu").toggle();
        $("#alert").toggle();
    });

          /*
          $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre'));
          } );
          */

    }
    else{
        $('#centre-class-menu').slideDown();
        $('.centre-year-selection').attr('data-attendance-check', $('#class_date').val());

         $(".centre-year-selection").click(function(){
        $("centre-class-menu").toggle();
    });
        /*
        $( ".centre-year-selection" ).each(function() {
            $( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-referrer')+ '&report_date_start='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check')+ '&report_date_end='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&report_range='+ $( this ).attr('data-report-range'));
          });
        */
          }

};

</script>

<?php } ?>

<?php
 break;case "edit": ?>



  <?php 
            break;
        case "new":
            ?>


  <?php
 break;} ?>
```

### Edit

After seeing the html, if have learned that `data-subject` is present in multiple classes, which obviously makes it impossible to get the right value sent.

```
 <strong>All Subjects<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></strong>
                            </a> 
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="GCSE Maths"   data-report-range="month">
                                      GCSE Maths <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="GCSE English"   data-report-range="month">
                                      GCSE English <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="GCSE Science"   data-report-range="month">
                                      GCSE Science <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="GCSE Art"   data-report-range="month">
                                      GCSE Art <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="GCSE Sociology"   data-report-range="month">
                                      GCSE Sociology <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="OCR Nationals ICT"   data-report-range="month">
                                      OCR Nationals ICT <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="OCR Nationals Sports"   data-report-range="month">
                                      OCR Nationals Sports <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="OCR Nationals Business Studies"   data-report-range="month">
                                      OCR Nationals Business Studies <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="Entry Science"   data-report-range="month">
                                      Entry Science <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="Functional Skills English"   data-report-range="month">
                                      Functional Skills English <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="Functional Skills Maths"   data-report-range="month">
                                      Functional Skills Maths <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="ESOL"   data-report-range="month">
                                      ESOL <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         
                                                         <a href="#" class="small-box-footer" data-id="<?php=$Referrer_Name?>"   data-subject="Preparation for Working Life"   data-report-range="month">
                                      Preparation for Working Life <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                    </a>         

                          </div>
                    </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: In your first code snippet, are you trying to access `$_REQUEST` value from within single-quoted string?

Comment: @lolbas: Yes. That is true.

Comment: This code is very large, and does not meet the requirements of a [mcve]. I wonder if the question should be put on hold. Additionally, did the answers below help at all, Fahad?

Answer (score 1):

A few comments can be made without further context:

- The injected javascript values are not being escaped (e.g. `$( this ).attr('data-centre')`). If, for example, they contain the following characters: `&` or `=` or `?`, the url syntax will be wrong and you may not get all values on the server side.
- Did you try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` on the server side to debug? Are you sure you're not getting all values? Be sure to put it as early on the script as possible, so that they're values are not mutated by some rogue piece of code introduced by your bad programmer.
- Did you try putting the whole assembled javascript string into a variable and then `console.log`ging it to see if it's coming out properly?

i.e.

```
    $(".centre-selection").each(function() {
       var string = '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>...'; 
       console.log(string); 
       $( this ).attr( 'href', string); });
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no key `module_action` at all in the urls you are generating.

Apart from that, you need to encode the values correctly for use in a url.

In php, you can use `urlencode()` and in javascript, you can use `encodeURIComponent()`.

So the line where you build the url in javascript, should look more or less like:

```
$( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=urlencode($_REQUEST['module']);?>&Subject=' 
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-subject')) + '&Centre_Selected_ID='
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-all-centre')) + '&StartDate='
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('report_date_start')) + '&EndDate='
    + encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end')));
```

If there are any more problems, you should post the surrounding code as it is not clear if you are echoing from php or directly writing javascript.